# alternative for onedit when change is not done by user but by script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an Onedit function that triggers a copy to target function.
It works perfect when I put in OK in column AK manually. But when I use the following script to setValue OK in column AK, it doesn't work anymore.
I know that an Onedit function only works by user edit, but I would like to know if there's a workaround so my function keeps on working without personal interference.

```
OnEdit
`function onEdit() {

var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var data = s.getDataRange().getValues();

 if( s.getName() == "Formulierreacties 1" ) { //ON EDITS in tabblad 'Fomulierreacties 1'
  var r = s.getActiveCell();

  if( r.getColumn() == 37 ) { //
    if( r.getValue() === "OK" ) //kolom AK = 'OK'  Zoja kopieer naar tabblad 'Aanvragen 
        push2AANVRAAG();} //kopieert de Aanvraag naar tabblad "Aanvragen

          }

}`
```

```
var MASTERSHEET_ID = '1XHtCB2iq4vggAmWQ85GOoazzOVhLRWJs_Akp_eTAdrc';

function CopyAanvraag()
{
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(MASTERSHEET_ID).getSheetByName('Formulierreacties 1');
  var data = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i=1;i<data.length;i++)
  {  
     var rowData = data[i];
     if (rowData[0] != "" && rowData[33]=="Complete" && rowData[36] != "OK") 
     {
       sourceSheet. getRange(i+1,37). setValue("OK");
     }         
  }
}
```

```
function push2AANVRAAG() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var master = ss.getSheetByName('Formulierreacties 1');
  var dest = ss.getSheetByName('Aanvragen'); //Destination sheet
  var currentRowNumber = ss.getActiveSelection().getRowIndex();  // neemt de rijnummer van de actieve cel
  var selectedFullRangeC = master.getRange(currentRowNumber,9,1,1); // capteert: rijn°(auto), kolomn°(I), #rij(1), #kolom(1)): |functie|
  var selectedFullRangeI = master.getRange(currentRowNumber,10,1,1); // capteert: rijn°(auto), kolomn°(J), #rij(1), #kolom(1)): |Aantal gevraagd|
  var selectedFullRangeG = master.getRange(currentRowNumber,16,1,1); // capteert: rijn°(auto), kolomn°(P), #rij(1), #kolom(1)): |Business unit|
  var selectedFullRangeD = master.getRange(currentRowNumber,17,1,1); // capteert: rijn°(auto), kolomn°(Q), #rij(1), #kolom(1)): |functiecategorie|
  var selectedFullRangeH = master.getRange(currentRowNumber,21,1,1); // capteert: rijn°(auto), kolomn°(U), #rij(1), #kolom(1)): |Tewerkstellingsplaats|
  var selectedFullRangeF = master.getRange(currentRowNumber,22,1,1); // capteert: rijn°(auto), kolomn°(V), #rij(1), #kolom(1)): |Startdatum|    
  var selectedFullRangeA = master.getRange(currentRowNumber,33,1,1); // capteert: rijn°(auto), kolomn°('AG'), #rij(1), #kolom(1)):|ordernr|
  var selectedFullRangeB = master.getRange(currentRowNumber,35,1,1); // capteert: rijn°(auto), kolomn°(AI), #rij(1), #kolom(1)): |Datum aanvraag goedgekeurd uit detailed approved|*/
  var selectedFullRangeE = master.getRange(currentRowNumber,36,1,1); // capteert: rijn°(auto), kolomn°(AJ), #rij(1), #kolom(1)): |Loonklasse|

     dest.insertRows(3)

     var destRange_NEWLINE = dest.getRange(3,1);// Kopiëert rij 2 (1 verborgen rij) en kolom 'A'tem kolom 'Q' (17 kolommen) naar nieuwe rij 3 
     dest.getRange(2,1,1,17).copyTo(destRange_NEWLINE);    
       
     var destRangePOS2A = dest.getRange(3,1);// destRangePOS2A = nieuwe rij 3 & naar 1ste kolom(A)
     selectedFullRangeA.copyTo(destRangePOS2A,{contentsOnly: true});// 
     
     var destRangePOS2B = dest.getRange(3,2);// destRangePOS2B = nieuwe rij 3 & naar 2de kolom(B)
     selectedFullRangeB.copyTo(destRangePOS2B,{contentsOnly: true});// 
      
      var destRangePOS2C = dest.getRange(3,3);// destRangePOS2C = nieuwe rij 3 & naar 3de kolom(C)
     selectedFullRangeC.copyTo(destRangePOS2C,{contentsOnly: true});// 

      var destRangePOS2D = dest.getRange(3,4);// destRangePOS2D = nieuwe rij 3 & naar 4de kolom(D)
     selectedFullRangeD.copyTo(destRangePOS2D,{contentsOnly: true});// 

      var destRangePOS2E = dest.getRange(3,5);// destRangePOS2E = nieuwe rij 3 & naar 5de kolom(E)
     selectedFullRangeE.copyTo(destRangePOS2E,{contentsOnly: true});// 

      var destRangePOS2F = dest.getRange(3,6);// destRangePOS2F = nieuwe rij 3 & naar 6de kolom(F)
     selectedFullRangeF.copyTo(destRangePOS2F,{contentsOnly: true});// 

     var destRangePOS2G = dest.getRange(3,7);// destRangePOS2G = nieuwe rij 3 & naar 7de kolom(G)
     selectedFullRangeG.copyTo(destRangePOS2G,{contentsOnly: true});// 

      var destRangePOS2H = dest.getRange(3,8);// destRangePOS2H = nieuwe rij 3 & naar 8de kolom(H)
     selectedFullRangeH.copyTo(destRangePOS2H,{contentsOnly: true});// 

      var destRangePOS2I = dest.getRange(3,9);// destRangePOS2I = nieuwe rij 3 & naar 9de kolom(I)
     selectedFullRangeI.copyTo(destRangePOS2I,{contentsOnly: true});// 

      //dest.getRange('A3').activate();  

    }
```

Copy certain cells to other tab upon change in first tab due to a timed script trigger

Comment: onEdit on fires on USER Edits not on changes caused by formulas or other scripts

Comment: I know, but is there an alternative script to trigger my function push2AANVRAAG() instead of OnEdit. I can't figure it out...

Comment: `push2AANVRAAG()` - perhaps you might explain what this function does, when/how you want it to fire, etc

Comment: I'll add the code of push2AANVRAAG() in my original question. It works in combination with the on edit function, but I don't find any other way to make it work.
It would be the most ideal that it works when there is a change in sourcesheet, but I can also add a timer trigger if that's not possible

Comment: `It works in combination with the on edit function` Well, why not run it as part of the 'onEdit' - you can even pass Event Objects across to it if that is useful.

Comment: I'm sorry... I don't understand what you mean with that.

Comment: You have an 'onEdit' that tests the sheet, column and value; if those are correct, it processes `push2AANVRAAG()`. But you say that your 'onEdit' "doesn't work anymore". Is that right? what does the Eexecutions tab show; does the script run, does it "fail" or "complete"? Do you also have a time-driven trigger for `push2AANVRAAG()`?

Comment: The script runs as "complete"